# Derivation of image displacement by prism

Tags: optics, imaging

d[image]When white light go through a prism it splits to the rainbow colors. I know a formula to calculate the displacement of an image when light goes through a prism, However, it is not wavelength dependent.

$
  d= f *tan(\theta)
\\
$

where $\theta$ is the deflection angle, f is the tube focal distance.

Basically what I need to know is that how light of different wavelengths bend when passed through a prism and how to calculate the shifting on the screen (camera). What I have in mind is in an optical imaging system.

Comment: It looks like you are using the displacement for a lens of focal length f, and input angle of theta.  That formula does not describe the angular displacement of a beam due to a prism.  It might help if you draw the full system of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JB2 thanks, I have edited my post.